# How to add a JCheckBox column to my JTable without using models?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I wanted to add a `JCheckBox` column to my `JTable` without using models. I searched and found some solutions like using models but they are not what I wanted because my project is at its latest stage and might provide some problems and I don't know how to use Models as well. If anyone can help me find a solution I'll be grateful.

```
for (int cnt = 0; myStudent.currentCourses[cnt] != 0; cnt++){
    for (course c : Courses) {
        if (myStudent.currentCourses[cnt] == c.getCourseNum() && myStudent.groupNum[cnt] == c.getGroupsContained()) {

            data[cnt][0] = String.valueOf(c.getCourseNum());
            data[cnt][1] = String.valueOf(myStudent.groupNum[cnt]);
            data[cnt][2] = String.valueOf(c.getUnits());
            data[cnt][3] = c.getCourseName();
            data[cnt][4] = String.valueOf(c.getSignedNum());
            data[cnt][5] = c.getProfessorName();
            data[cnt][6] = c.getExamDate();
            data[cnt][7] = c.getClassSchedule();
            data[cnt][8] = c.getPrerequisites();
            data[cnt][9] = c.getExtraInfo();
        }
    }
}

courseTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

Just to clarify some things that might confuse you (the whole code is about 800 lines). `myStudent` is an specific object from a `student` class and `Courses` is an `ArrayList` of a `course` class (the `course` class has some properties and I set my data with that specific course information using getters). I want to add `JCheckBox` column to my table for this reason: if the user choose some courses by checkbox (consider we have 4 courses) and then presses a button under the table, I want to remove that course (row) from the table dynamically.

Comment: 1) *"I wanted to add a `JCheckBox` column to my `JTable` without using models."* reads like *"I want to make an internal combustion engine without using wheels"*. 2) *"I don't know how to use Models as well."* Now's a good time to learn. It'd take less effort (and time) than implementing a custom solution that **doesn't** use a table model. See [How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for details & example code.

Comment: Thanks for your help...Yeah now I have my JCheckBox in myTable using a custom table model extending AbstractTableModel...but Unfortunately I'm facing another problem...As I found out there isn't any specific method to remove a row after my ChechBox value changes to true since my data is an array object...I mean if the user changes the value of some rows to true by clicking on its ChechBox and then presses a JButton I want my rows to be removed...I wonder if you could help me with this because I don't have much time left to finish this project...Thanks in advance <3

Comment: *"since my data is an array object"* Put it in a changeable list structure like a `Vector` or an `ArrayList`. *"I wonder if you could help me"* That's what I have been trying to do.. *"I don't have much time left to finish this project"* Oops. Nope. I prefer to help people with good time management skills. It's generally a bad idea to mention time constraints - they are relevant only to you, and there are plenty of people asking for (free) help who **can** manage them.

Comment: You are getting hard on me bro:)))... I have been working on this for a week and It's the only part of the project I've got stuck at...Anyway thanks so much...I learned a lot from you